# can we create html tags using eval method in javascript

Tags: javascript

i found some code which is using anchor tags in eval

```
eval("a='http://google.co.in'+window .location.href");
```

The code does not yield an error at the same time it is not redirecting to the desired page. By observing this piece of code i want to know whether javascript `eval()` can be used to create html tags like `eval('script tag')` or not.

Comment: eval is used to evaluate javascript code not html, if you want to redirect to another page just use: `document.location.href = 'whatever.com'`.  In order to create HTML tags use `var a = document.createElement( 'A' );`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) does *only* evaluate JavaScript code. To fetch a DOM tree from a string, one of the following methods can be used:

1. Set the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) property of a DOM element.
2. [`document.write('..html here..')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write) and [`document.writeln('..html here...')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/document.writeln).
   Warning: The last method will overwrite the current document when the page has already finished loading.

Examples:

1. `document.body.innerHTML = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack</a>';`
   Replaces the body with a single link.
2. `document.write('<a href="http://st.tk">Test</a>');`