# Script to be executed in a Div loaded by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to load an HTML page inside a `div`, but this page has scripts that don't work if I load the AJAX code using the click function. The problem is that I need the page to execute the scripts when I click some specific button.

The code that works, but load with main page, not when I click the button:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "primeiro/index.html",
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#curso").html(data);
        $('#curso').each(function (index, element) { 
            eval(element.innerHTML); 
        });
    });
});
```

I change to this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#loginsb").click(function () { 
        $.ajax({
            url: "primeiro/index.html",
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("#curso").html(data);
            $('#curso').each(function(index, element) { 
                eval(element.innerHTML); 
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Then the page seems to be "paused", so, can't load the script.

How can I use the click (in `#loginsb` button) function to load the content inside my `div`?

Thanks!

Comment: Your use of an `each()` loop on an `id` selector implies there are multiple elements in your page with the same id, which would make the HTML invalid. You should change those to classes instead.

Comment: What exactly is returned by the ajax? `eval()` doesn't seem to be the way to go about this.

Comment: Rory, I change the Id to Class and the problem still here. Meldon, I'm new to ajax, so I found this code on SO and it works (loading with my main page), just when I try to use a button to start the action the problem appears. Any idea to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your html? In any case, I would try debugging step-by-step: replace the ajax call by a simple alert() or console.log() to check the click is registered and if it is, log the data in the .done function and see if that runs

Comment: You may want to look at this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820096/can-we-create-html-tags-using-eval-method-in-javascript.  You can get all scripts from a page by document.scripts and then append them to the main page document.  eval() doesn't work on HTML stuff, only script.

Comment: Thanks, Leng! I change the eval value to document.writeIn and still working only when I use the window load to execute the ajax script. When I use a button the content seems to be paused.